# C# Unity - How to find the name of a field/property? Alternatively how to set up an Item Attributes system? (HealOnUse, Damage, Condition, etc)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, design-patterns, database-design

Im trying to design a robust Item system that can be used in Inventories but can also be serialized and saved easily. I use JSON for serialization, but thats not what this Q is about.

So I have a bunch of `ItemSO`'s as `ScriptableObjects`, they come in all Types like, `Fish, Wood, Cooked_Food, etc.`

```
public enum ItemsEnum { Fish, Cooked_Food, Wood }

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "ItemSO", menuName = "Scriptables/ItemSO", order = 11)]
[System.Serializable]
public class ItemSO : ItemBaseSO
{
    public ItemsEnum Type;

}
```

I also have a bunch of `ToolSO`'s such as `Rock_Axe, Iron_Axe, Steel_Axe, etc`

```
public enum ToolEnum { Fishing, Woodcutting, Cooking, Melee, Ranged }

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "ToolSO", menuName = "Scriptables/ToolSO", order = 11)]
[System.Serializable]
public class ToolSO : ItemBaseSO
{
    public byte ToolTier;

    [Range(1.0f, 4.0f)]
    public float ToolEfficiency;
    public ToolEnum Type;
}
```

Both these inherit from ItemBaseSO:

```
public class ItemBaseSO : ScriptableObject
{
    public short ID;
    public string Description;


    [Expandable]
    public ItemAttributeBase[] Attributes;
}
```

Thats where the fun starts, and where my headache begins aswell.

ItemAttributeBase is just an empty Container that I Inherit from like so:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "ATR_Condition", menuName = "Scriptables/Item Attributes/ATR_Condition", order = 14)]
public class ItemATR_Condition : ItemAttributeBase
{
    public short Condition = 100;

    public override object GetAttribute()
    {
        return Condition;
    }
}
```

and:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "ATR_Heal", menuName = "Scriptables/Item Attributes/ATR_Heal", order = 14)]
public class ItemATR_Heal : ItemAttributeBase
{
    public short HealAmount = 10;

    public override object GetAttribute()
    {
        return HealAmount;
    }
}
```

The downside of this is I have to create a new Attribute for every single possibility, so I will have `ATR_Heal_10, ATR_Heal_15, ATR_Heal_20` and so on... But thats okay.

The real problem is in the following Item.cs script, its not a Scriptable Object, but a custom Class, this is what I actually save to JSON and its values can change over time (for example `Condition` will decrease over time until the Item breaks):

```
public Item(ToolSO toolSO)
{
    this.ItemType = (byte)toolSO.Type;
    this.Name = toolSO.name;
    this.ID = toolSO.ID;
    this.Description = toolSO.Description;

    if (toolSO.Attributes.Length < 1) return;

    foreach (ItemAttributeBase attributeBase in toolSO.Attributes)
    {
        object attribute = attributeBase.GetAttribute();
        if (attribute is nameof(Condition)) // pseudo-code
        {
            this.Condition = (short)attribute;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Here im trying to set the `Item`'s `Condition` from the `ItemSO`, if the ItemSO has that `Condition_Attribute`, calling attributeBase.GetAttribute() returns an `object` as seen above in the `ATR_Condition Class`.

How do I figure out from this returned `Attribute object`, if that Attribute object is the property Condition, or is it Damage? Or maybe its HealAmount?

The AttributeBase is great because I can just slot in anything that inherits from it, and so I can easily combine different Attributes in the same Array, but then the downside and what makes this approach impossible now, is that I have no way of knowing what the actual Attribute is when I only have access to the base Class (`ItemAttributeBase`):

```
public class ItemAttributeBase : ScriptableObject
{
    public virtual object GetAttribute() { return null; }
}
```

Sorry for the long post. the gist of my Q is: How do I find out what object im dealing with if I only have access to the base class.
If the solution is non-performant or this is simply the wrong way to design an Item System, then please provide in your answer a different design.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since GetAttribute always returns a short, testing it's type isn't going to help. You may as well just return the short instead of an object.

You can test whether attributeBase is a particular derived class though.

```
foreach (ItemAttributeBase attributeBase in toolSO.Attributes
{
    // is it a ItemATR_Condition
    if (attributeBase is ItemATR_Condition)
    {
        // yes, so cast it to an ItemATR_Condition
        ItemATR_Condition condition = attributeBase as ItemATR_Condition;
        this.condition = condition.GetAttribute();
    }
}
```

However, it's worth noting that while this is fine, having to check if a derived class is of a certain type is kinda missing the point of polymorphism, and could mean that you should rethink your code.

For example, you could pass the item or the condition to an overridden method of the Attribute, then each different attribute could decide what to do with it. I'm not saying that's the best solution, just something to think about.

**Edit:**
Adding a suggestion for the polymorphic approach. I don't know if this works for your particular use case, it's just something to think about.

In you ItemAttributeBase class, define an abstract method ApplyAttribute(Item item);

```
public class ItemAttributeBase : ScriptableObject
{
    public virtual object GetAttribute() { return null; }
    public abstract void ApplyAttribute(Item item);
}
```

Now in each of your derived attribute classes implement the method.

```
public class ItemATR_Condition : ItemAttributeBase
{
    public short Condition = 100;

    public override object GetAttribute()
    {
        return Condition;
    }
 
    public override void ApplyAttribute(Item item)
    {
        // do whatever you need with the item here.
        item.condition = Condition;

        // or item.health += health or whatever.
    }
}
```

Now in your Item class, when you loop through the attributes:

```
foreach (ItemAttributeBase attributeBase in toolSO.Attributes)
{
    // you could still type check here if you only want
    // to handle certain types of attributes i guess.
    attributeBase.ApplyAttribute(this);
}
```

The compiler is smart enough to call the method on the correct derived class.
The advantage is that each attribute deals with the item itself, therefore no type checks are required.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
I could also return the entire Class(ATR_Condition or ATR_Heal, doesnt matter), and then check if the returned value is of type ATR_Condition, if it is cast it to ATR_Condition and go from there... Or is that even messsier?
Also all attributes as examples are by coincidence shorts, but I also have attributes that are a bool for example.

Comment: @questioneeeeer Having the item check for every kind of attribute seems like it could get out of control the more attributes and items you add, and bypasses OO's best feature - polymorphism. Then again, sometimes it's easier to just check the type and cast. A simpler solution might be something like attributeBase.ApplyAttribute(item); Then you don't need to check anything, each attribute deals with the item in it's own way. Like I said, I don't know if that's the best solution for you. Which is easier to handle? Which scales better? Which makes cleaner code? You'll have to test it out.

Comment: I will try your suggestions, but I dont understand how to use attributeBase.ApplyAttribute(item), if you can amend your answer with a simple example I would appreciate it as it might help me a bunch with this problem.

Comment: @questioneeeeer I've added some example code. Bear in mind that I don't know if it's appropriate for your use case, it's just an example.

Comment: Thanks again, one final question when calling this:   
`
    public override void ApplyAttribute(Item item)
    {
        // do whatever you need with the item here.
        item.condition = Condition;

        // or item.health += health or whatever.
    }
`
Does it modify the original item? Or should it return the modified item from the override, instead of void, and then use that returning item to set the original?

Comment: @questioneeeeer If Item is a class it will be passed by reference, therefore it will modify the original. No need to return anything unless you want to.